# More than one character on Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just wondering, I'm about to buy it and it sounds awesome, but how many characters can I have in Skyrim on the PS3? Am I limited to just 1, or can I make more than one character at once?

Comment: What do you mean "how many guys or girls you're able to have", you mean followers?

Comment: if followers, see answer below. if you mean children/s, you would need a dlc(hearthfire) and limited to only 2.

Answer (score 6):

If you're referring to how many character saves: As many as your harddrive has room for.

If you're referring to followers: Generally the rule stops at two. One follower, and one Dog (or Troll, depending on your DLC). However this is fairly fluid as there are quests in which you automatically gain a follower, and will stay with you to the mission end. And, just with almost every other part of the game, can be "Hacked" to gain additional permanent followers. (I stopped at a posse of 7).

[This wiki page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Multiple_Followers) describes multiple followers more clearly if you are interested.

Comment: not entirely infinite, infinite implies limitless which isn't the case as you are limited by your harddrive space, though given hard drive sizes it's near infinite but a 1.5 GB 360 harddrive does have a limit on it if your like my dad and don't overwrite save files, has the possibility of being very limited

Comment: very true. Shall edit the question :P

Comment: Follower limit can also be removed by mods. I know there are mods that allow you to have a whole army following you.

Comment: In my current play through I have 4 follower (5 when I have a follower from a quest). I don't recommend to use more followers as they start block each other as well as quest NPCs in indoor areas.

Comment: Oh he'll yeah. There was one situation where I had 6 followers, I was on an assassination quest in Whiterun... Let's just say, my followers thought it was a free-for-all... And within 3 minutes everyone was dead.

Comment: Don't use followers on assassination missions... they ruin them. Also... what's the fun in being an assassin if you run with "Doom Brigade" after you?

Comment: For the cheev's...

Answer (score 0):

## Character Saves

As many as the harddrive can handle.

## Followers

You can only have one human follower. Not possible unless [modded](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31581/?).

## Multiplayer

Todd Howard said there isn't going to be a multiplayer system in vanilla Skyrim. [Mods only](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/67038/?).

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one, but it's a bit convoluted. They're separate save sections, and to get to the saves for one character you have to press confirm on the characters names, then you can go back out and save.
Using diagram below, if you're currently playing character 1 and go into character 2's load section and exit out, your autosaves will start overwriting 2's and not 1's, so you have to make sure you're in character 1's load section

so:
start -> System -> load
"show all saves"
"*character 1*"
"*character 2*"
and this is totally reversible, meaning two people can have a skyrim character on one PS account! i literally just discovered this less than 15 mins ago and i've had this game since 2011...bit embarrassing... lol